# Angular Migration failed

Tags: angular, angular-upgrade

I'm trying to update my project from **~10.1.6** to **11** with command:

```
ng update @angular/core@11 @angular/cli@11
```

error is

```
Package "@ng-select/ng-select" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/common" (requires ">=9.0.0 <10.0.0" (extended), would install "11.2.14").
                  Package "@ng-select/ng-select" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/core" (requires ">=9.0.0 <10.0.0" (extended), would install "11.2.14").
                  Package "@ng-select/ng-select" has an incompatible peer dependency to "@angular/forms" (requires ">=9.0.0 <10.0.0" (extended), would install "11.2.14").
✖ Migration failed: Incompatible peer dependencies found.
Peer dependency warnings when installing dependencies means that those dependencies might not work correctly together.
You can use the '--force' option to ignore incompatible peer dependencies and instead address these warnings later.
  See "/tmp/ng-qLRhlg/angular-errors.log" for further details.
```

My ng version is:

```
     _                      _                 ____ _     ___
    / \   _ __   __ _ _   _| | __ _ _ __     / ___| |   |_ _|
   / △ \ | '_ \ / _` | | | | |/ _` | '__|   | |   | |    | |
  / ___ \| | | | (_| | |_| | | (_| | |      | |___| |___ | |
 /_/   \_\_| |_|\__, |\__,_|_|\__,_|_|       \____|_____|___|
                |___/
    

Angular CLI: 14.0.1
Node: 16.15.1
Package Manager: npm 8.11.0 
OS: linux x64

Angular: 
... 

Package                      Version
------------------------------------------------------
@angular-devkit/architect    0.1400.1 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/core         14.0.1 (cli-only)
@angular-devkit/schematics   14.0.1 (cli-only)
@schematics/angular          14.0.1 (cli-only)
```

If I use --force flag, after update I can't install packages.

probably the problem with npm or nodejs?